# How to bring to front a control at design time without manually moving controls?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, designer

My application has 3 panels on the same position that I hide/show with a combo box.
Is it possible, in such a design, to move one of these panels to the front without moving controls but simply by changing their properties or code in `designer.cs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can from *.designer !

[image]
As you see now Panel2 is like Bring to Front.

Just manipulate this.Controls.Add()  with your panel orders which will came first !

Thanks Baby !

Answer (score 0):

After selecting the desired control in the drop-down list at the top of the Properties panel, just hit the Esc key on your keyboard to change the focus to the corresponding graphical element in the Designer.

This enables the Bring to Front button on the application toolbar and allows one to nudge the control around with the arrow keys on the keyboard without dragging it (because dragging it can cause the control to switch parents).